# Pydantic data model with nested dict

Tags: python, pydantic

I have the following question about a pydantic setup. I work with python 3.11 and pydantic 2.5.

i have a config file which includes data like this:

```
data = {
    'project': 'abc',
    'id': 12345,
    'software': {
        'aaa': {
            'version': '20.1.2.2013',
            'path': '//path_to_software/aaa'
        }, 
        'bbb': {
            'version': '4.0.2',
            'path': '//path_to_software/bbb'
        }, 
        'ccc': {
            'version': '10.0v1',
            'path': '//path_to_software/ccc'
        }
    }
}
```

And my pydantic model looks like this:

```
class SoftwareVersion(pydantic.BaseModel):
    version: str
    path: pathlib.Path

class Software(pydantic.BaseModel):
    aaa: SoftwareVersion
    bbb: SoftwareVersion
    ccc: SoftwareVersion

class Project(pydantic.BaseModel):
    project: str
    id: int
    software: Software
```

So far so good everything works fine. But i want to validate each software versions and see if it has the right format. Can i somehow write a validator method in SoftwareVersion/Software class or is it better to have a own class for each software version?
Like this (i only did the class for software aaa)? I would prefer not to go down this road because i think its less readable. But is that the sandard way of doing it?

```
class SoftwareVersionAAA(pydantic.BaseModel):
    version: str
    path: pathlib.Path

    @pydantic.field_validator("version")
    def check_version(cls, value):
        if not bool(re.match(r'^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$', str(value))):
            raise ValueError("Wrong version format!")
        return value

class Software(pydantic.BaseModel):
    aaa: SoftwareVersionAAA
    bbb: SoftwareVersionBBB
    ccc: SoftwareVersionCCC

class Project(pydantic.BaseModel):
    project: str
    id: int
    software: Software
```

Furthermore if one of the fields () dont exist i want to create it and fill its value with a standard value. Whats the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the `version` field`s format depend on the software type (aaa, bbb, ccc)? Is it possible to create the universal regexp template?

Comment: Do you really need to have exactly that structure? I would turn the `software` field into list of `SoftwareVersion` and include software type into this model

Comment: The version field is always a string but the format is different depending on the software. It could be like in the data dict above (0.0.0.0, 0.0v0, 0.0.0 and so on). I would prefer not to change the config file, that would open upp a new rabbithole. I guess the easiest way would be to define a class for each software with a validator in it. Is that common practise for this kind of data structure?

Comment: I don't know about common practices, but you can 1) create different models for every type of software and validate `version` there, 2) create only one model `SoftwareVersion` and validate `version` in `model validator` of `Software` model.